# How to update field for multiple selection in TreeView of Odoo

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to select multiple employees in tree view and want to update their status (selection field having two options i.e. Present, Absent).

```py
status = fields.Selection(string="Status", selection=[('present', "Present"), ('absent', "Absent")])
```

My first approach:

I used `act_window` to create Present option in 'Actions' dropdown menu (which appears when multiple checkboxes are selected)

```xml
<act_window name="Present"
    res_model="hr.employee"
    src_model="hr.employee"
    multi="True"
    key2="client_action_multi"
    id="employee_present"
/>
```

And try to define a function for it in python file, but i can't link the 
    `act_window` to that function.

My second approach:

Then I try another method of creating a button and linked it to a javascript file but also this approach can't solve my problem.

Below is the content of file `hr_attendance/static/src/xml/qweb.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="sync_template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default sync_button" type="button">Present</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Below is the content of `sync.js hr_attendance/static/src/js`

```js
openerp.hr_attendance = function(instance) {
    var ListView = instance.web.ListView;
    console.log('Inside Javascript Code method call...');
    ListView.include({
        render_buttons: function() {
            // GET BUTTON REFERENCE
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
            if (this.$buttons) {
                var btn = this.$buttons.find('.sync_button')
            }
            
            // PERFORM THE ACTION
            btn.on('click', this.proxy('do_sync'))
        },
        do_sync: function() {
            new instance.web.Model('hr.attendance')
            .call('present', [[]])
            .done(function() {
                alert('done')
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the function which i am calling in javascript code

```py
@api.multi
def present(self):
    self.write({'status': 'present'})
```

Comment: Edit your question to show us the code (related to your problem) you have by the moment, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice community module called "Mass Editing" in the [OCA Repositories](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/98cde166a8fa534e757b263cff5bc15669630447/mass_editing). You can really easy create mass edit actions for business objects like employees and just activate them for the action menu ("More" in Odoo V8).

Another solution is to create a server action with python code. Server actions can be activated for the action menu, too (there is a button in the right corner of a odoo V8 server action). But you will need two actions, where the first solution works with one action.

The code for this server actions is really easy:

```py
obj.browse(env.context.get('active_ids')).write({'my_field': my_value})
```

You obviously have to write on your selection field and the value for one server action is "Present" and "Absent" for the other.

Server Actions can be found in Settings/technical/Actions/Server Actions.

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner. I can see Server Actions in Action Menu. But where I have to put the python logic to update the status?

Comment: You have to change the type of the action, to make the text field visible.

Comment: Actually you should per default already see a text field with lots of commented python lines. Just put the one liner of my answer right after them or override them.